# Optimal Stopping for Unknown Number of Candidates

Tags: statistics, mathematical-optimization

In the secretary problem, the optimal strategy is to reject the first n/e and start selecting the best that is better than the best one in the n/e candidates. For example, if the number of candidates is 100, we reject the first 37 candidates then start selecting the best one. This is the simplest form of the theory, what about if the number of the candidate is not not known what will be the best strategy, or in other words, when should we start selecting/accepting candidates.

Comment: Have you read Bruss (1984), [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2243336) and references therein? I think you may find it quite illuminating.

Comment: Dear aws, code you post some code to illustrate what did you tried. However basically your question looks more suitable for stat, math or computer science Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @N.Wouda What if k>1 in the case of unknown N? We might know the distribution of n and also we have an upper bound on n. we might also assume n=>k

Answer (score 0):

In case of unknown number of candidates the stopping rule is no longer valid and depends on prior probability distribution or use 1/e law of best choice. Please see [Unknown Number of Participants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem#Unknown_number_of_applicants) & [Best Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem#1/e-law_of_best_choice).